# Django - beginner- what is the process for passing information to a view via a url?

Tags: python, django

I am working on my first django project which is also my first backend project. In the tutorials/reading I have completed, I haven't come across passing information back to django without a modelform.

My intention is to calculate a value on a page using javascript and pass it to django when a user hits a submit button on that page. The submit button will also be a link to another page. I know I could process the information in a view via the url if I knew how to pass the information back to django.

I'm aware that django uses MVC and as I have my models and views in place, I am lead to believe that this has something to do with controllers.

Basically, I would like to know how to pass information from a page to django as a user follows a link to another page. I understand that this isn't the place for long step by step tutorials on specific topics but I would appreciate any links to resources on this subject. I don't know what this process is even called so I can't search documentation for it.

EDIT:
From further reading, I think that I want to be using the submit button to GET or POST the value. In this particular case, POST is probably better. Could someone confirm that this is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, generally POST is a better way of submitting data than GET. There is a bit of a confusion about terminology in Django. While Django is, indeed MVC, models are models, but views are in fact controllers and views are templates. Since you are going to use AJAX to submit and retrieve the data, you don't care about templates. So what you most likely want is something like this

in your urls.py as part of your urlpatterns variable

```
url(r'mything/$', MyView.as_view())
```

in your views.py

```
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

class MyView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.POST
        ... do your thing ...
        return HttpResponse(results)
```

and in your javascript

```
jQuery.post('/mything/', data, function() { whatever you do here })
```

Answer (score 1):

There're many ways, you can achieve this in django. Following are the two ways, that I generally prefer :-

1)   As a query string parameter in the URL

```
 eg. http://localhost/getPatientInfo?patientId=23&name=Sachin
```

2)   Making URL dynamic, to include the information in the view itself.

```
 eg. http://localhost/patientInfo/23/Sachin
```

In case 1:-
You will have to do,

```
patientId = request.GET["patientId"]
name      = request.GET["patientName"]
```

In case 2:
Your URL conf will be something like :

```
urls = [
  url("^patientInfo/(\d+)/([^/]+)$", yourViewFunc)
]
```

And in your view func :-

```
   def yourViewFunc(request, patientId, patientName):
       # your logic goes here
       pass
```

For info. related to URLConf, refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think I wasn't clear enough in saying that I didn't want to use model data and pass that to a url. I wanted to generate a variable on a page, probably using javascript. When the user clicks a submit button, I want that variable to be passed to django so I can process it in the url's view.

Comment: @Era you can pass the JS variable through a link. For example yourwebsite.com/jsvar. You need to do the appropriate setups in urls and view before doing that.